# Not applying index on solr search

Tags: solr

I am developing an algorithm which fetches result from solr but when I pass ids in my sequence  to solr to fetch details of those ids solr sorts out the result in sorted order of ids which I dont want.
I dont want the scoring mechanism on ids i.e.

```
 q:(ids:61212^100 61211^99)
```

Because my count of ids are 500 for which solr hangs up for search

Comment: So what do you want to sort on? If you don't want any scores to be considered, just dropping the `^xx` part should be enough. Solr doesn't have any problem with retrieving 500 ids - but the query you're looking for is probably `q=ids:(61212 61211)` - with `q.op=OR`, or with `OR` inserted between each term.

Comment: I don't want sort my data. i just need to pull all data of user based in his id

Comment: In that case, `q=id:(61212 61211)` should give you two documents - the one with id 61212 and the one with id 61211.

Comment: It gives me first document of 61211 and then 61212. But i need 61212 first  and then 61211

Comment: So then you want sorting. You want them sorted by the sequence you supply them in?

Comment: Correct. I want them in order in which I supply them

Comment: Can you reorder the sequence after you've queried Solr? (retrieving 500 docs can be a cheap operation, and if you're retrieving them all anyway, doing a quick sort of the documents list after retrieving them will probably be more efficient)

Comment: Its very heavy operation for sorting at code level. Currently its been implemented the same way just I thought to sort it in solr so that optimize the work load